# Why is flexbox not pushing subsequent content down when it's items are wrapped?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

My layout works fine until the `for collectors` div wraps. At this point, the subsequent `what artists are saying` div does not get pushed below the wrapped content. Anyone know why?

I've tried setting `align-content` of the `for collectors' flex box to various settings.

*P.S. Using Tailwind.css*

### Showing when element is not wrapped

not wrapped:

[image]

### Showing when element is wrapped

when wrapped:

[image]

### HTML

```
    <!-- for artist-for collectors -->
        <div class="for-artists-and-collectors flex flex-wrap">

            <div class="flex justify-start h-full bg-red">

                <div class="for-container flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full bg-black px-8">
                    <h2 class="text-white pb-2">For Artists</h2>
                    <div class="text-sm text-white text-left pb-4">
                        I want to auction my artwork using K****o
                    </div>
                    <k-button style="height: 40px;">Create Account -></k-button>
                </div>

                <div class="for-artists-bg h-full flex-grow flex-shrink"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="flex justify-start h-full bg-green">

                <div class="for-container flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full bg-gray px-8">
                    <h2 class="text-white pb-2">For Collectors</h2>
                    <div class="text-sm text-white text-left pb-4">
                        I want to discover & bid on original artwork
                    </div>
                    <k-button style="height: 40px;">Browse Auctions -></k-button>
                </div>

                <div class="for-collectors-bg h-full flex-grow flex-shrink"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /for artist-for collectors -->

        <!-- what artists are saying -->
        <div class="flex content-between">

            <div class="waas flex flex-col items-end">

                <h2 class="text-black waas-title text-right mb-6">
                    What artists are saying
                </h2>

                <div class="waas-controls flex">
                    <k-button 
                        style="height: 40px; width: 40px;" 
                        color="white"
                        class="mr-2">
                        <left-arrow-black />
                    </k-button>
                    <k-button style="height: 40px; width: 40px;">
                        <left-arrow-white class="right-arrow" />
                    </k-button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="artist-profile">

            </div>
        </div>
```

### Style

```
.for-artists-and-collectors {
    height: 220px;
}

.for-artists-and-collectors > div {
    flex:  1 1 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.for-artists-bg {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1482245294234-b3f2f8d5f1a4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80");
    background-position: center center;
}

.for-collectors-bg {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536574753884-8c45a0431ecf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80");
    background-position: center center;
}

.for-container {
    max-width: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when an absolute height is set on the parent element and then a percentage height is set on child elements. At the I'm not aware of any other measurement combos that also cause the problem.

### Codepens

[Problem](https://codepen.io/Nanobrain/pen/WPQEJw) and the 
[Solution](https://codepen.io/Nanobrain/pen/ZwbJoy)

### Simplified Problem

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">child 1</div>
  <div class="child-2">child 2</div>
</div>

<div class="other">Other div</div>
```

-

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 80px;
}

.parent > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100%; /* this is the problem */
}

.child-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.child-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.other {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

### The solution

```
/* removed parent height */
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 50px; /* set an absolute height here */
}
```